# How can I call a parameterless class procedure with AsyncCalls?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7

Trying to integrate [AsyncCalls](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/) into one of my Delphi 7 projects, I haven't yet been able to call a parameterless procedure of a class.

**What I want to do:**

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
private
    procedure TestCalculation;
    procedure RunTest;
end;

var
  TestCall: IAsyncCall;

procedure TMyForm.RunTest;
begin
  TestCall := AsyncCall(TestCalculation);
end;
```

This is not possible, resulting in error E2036 Variable required (This error message occurs when you try to take the address of an expression or a constant.).

It is possible whenever my procedure has parameters like the `WaitForIt`procedure in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830714/1303011).
Furthermore it is possible for a `LocalAsyncCall` but I don't always want to declare local procedures.

And it is also possible to call this procedure if I make it static (i.e. `procedure TestCalculation` and not `procedure TMyForm.TesCalculation`). Then I can call successfully `RunTestCall := AsyncCall(@TestCalculation, []);` But this does not work for a procedure belonging to `TMyForm`.

**Question**

How can I call the parameterless class procedure in my example (`TestCalculation`) with AsyncCalls from another procedure within my class?

Comment: does asynccalls support anonymous methods, like OTL ? so you could wrap  that call into ad-hoc procedure ? like `AsyncCall( procedure (param:integer) begin TMyClass.MyMethod(); end)` ? Or perhaps you can use OmniThreadsLibrary ? For what i remember you can just `Parallel.Async( ProcedureName() )` but you can check it. At least OTL is not discontinued :-)

Comment: Unfortunately OTL does not support Delphi 7.

Comment: Bad luck.  OTL v.1.x ? though 1.x is not supported either :-) But really, you'd better tag your Delphi version, that is among TAGS' purpose afterall

Comment: My AsyncCall question addresses other Delphi versions also. I didn't intend to discuss OTL here. Thus I saw no need for a specific delphi version tag. Sorry.

Comment: Well, that still limits langauge or RTL features you cna use. Even if when someone suggests you  workarounds for AsyncCall, he might use some advanced feature, you don't know it for sure in advance. So i think a good trait is to mark you minimum version of Delphi anyway - just as the "least features" base that any provided answer should be compatible with. Jst my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AsyncCall` expects that you will pass a procedure that receives one parameter. If you don't want to pass a parameter, just add one and ignore it.

```
procedure TestCalculation(IgnoreMe: Integer);
....
TestCall := AsyncCall(TestCalculation, 0);
```

You can write an adapter to make the code cleaner for the caller:

```
type
  TAsyncCallParameterlessProc = procedure of object;

function AsyncCall(Proc: TAsyncCallParameterlessProc): IAsyncCall; overload;

......

type
  TAsyncCallParameterlessProcAdapter = class
  private
    FProc: TAsyncCallParameterlessProc;
  public
    constructor Create(Proc: TAsyncCallParameterlessProc);
    procedure IntegerProc(IgnoreMe: Integer);
  end;

{ TAsyncCallParameterlessProcAdapter }

constructor TAsyncCallParameterlessProcAdapter.Create(
  Proc: TAsyncCallParameterlessProc);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FProc := Proc;
end;

procedure TAsyncCallParameterlessProcAdapter.IntegerProc(IgnoreMe: Integer);
begin
  try
    FProc;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

function AsyncCall(Proc: TAsyncCallParameterlessProc): IAsyncCall;
var
  Adapter: TAsyncCallParameterlessProcAdapter;
begin
  Adapter := TAsyncCallParameterlessProcAdapter.Create(Proc);
  Result := AsyncCall(Adapter.IntegerProc, 0);
end;
```

With that adapter in place, the code in your question compiles and works.

Since AsyncCalls is discontinued, and will not be modified again, you could easily enough modify that code to support the usage you desire.

Personally I would modify `AsyncCalls` and add another sub class of `TInternalAsyncCall` to do the work.

As a really dirty hack, this would work:

```
type
  TAsyncCallParameterlessProc = procedure of object;

function AsyncCall(Proc: TAsyncCallParameterlessProc): IAsyncCall; overload;

.....

function AsyncCall(Proc: TAsyncCallParameterlessProc): IAsyncCall;
begin
  Result := AsyncCall(TAsyncCallArgIntegerEvent(Proc), 0);
end;
```

This relies on the fact that the integer parameter `TAsyncCallArgIntegerEvent` is passed in a volatile register. So, whilst the framework passes `0`, your procedure doesn't read it from the register.

Comment: I thought about it as a workaround but it looks so ugly and doesn't feel right.

Comment: I'd personally remove the `Parameterless` from names used in this code. If the procedure is e.g. with object parameter, it's defined as `TAsyncCallArgObjectProc`, so it's the `ArgObject` what specifies the parameter. I'd just keep it as `TAsyncCallProc`. [+1]

Comment: Tested, working. Thanks for sharing your wisdom ;-) Very nice.